# Merge 2 files and eliminates duplicates effectively R

Tags: r, data.table

I have two very big files that I have to merge and than eliminate duplicates according to one column. So far I am doing like this

```
myfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.dat")
myfilesContent <- lapply(myfiles, read.delim, header=F, quote="\"",sep=" ",colClasses="character")
data = as.data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(myfilesContent))
data <- data[!duplicated(data$V1,fromLast=TRUE),]
```

but reading the two files consumes a lot of memory. Is there a better way of doing it?

Many thanks

Comment: with consistent use of `data.table` instead of `data.frame` you should benefit from operations made by reference (in place) rather than copying data.frames in memory. Don't know if this is sufficient to your memory size though

Answer (score 1):

> but reading the two files consumes a lot of memory. Is there a better way of doing it?

Try `fread` instead of `read.delim`.
Yes keep using `rbindlist`.
Use `unique(...,by=V1)` on the `data.table` rather than converting it to `data.frame`.

Should be a lot faster and more memory efficient.